# error al momento de instalar chocolatey en Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

tengo un problema para poder instalar chocolatey ya vi varios tutoriales y no he encontrado una solución [image: les comparto la imagen para que puedan entender que es lo que me esta pasando]

Comment: debes agregarlo al path ejemplo cmd: `SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"` o en powershell `$env:Path += ";%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"`

Comment: Esa es una solución temporal. En su lugar deberías ejecutar `setx PATH "%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"`

Comment: Podrias poner el error en forma de texto por favor? En esta respuesta de meta se aclaran los motivos de este pedido: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: El termino ¨choco¨ no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyo una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo. En línea: 1 Carácter: 1, choco -v  + categoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (choco:string) [], CommandNotFoundException. +FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandFoundException

Comment: El problema en especifico me marca que debo borrar esta carpeta completamente: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey, además abrir las variables de entorno, buscar la de nombre choco y eliminar esa también, pero el detalle es que no conozco bien los comandos de windowsPowershell y eso es lo que me detiene. @DanteS.

Comment: Primero, yo no se nada de este lenguaje. Vi tu pregunta en las colas de revisión. Perdona. Segundo, me refería a que edites tu pregunta y agregues alli el error. Algo que no aclaré es que sea [con formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Cómo lo resolviste?

Answer (score 0):

Entra a la carpeta C:\ProgramData y elimina el directorio de chocolatey, luego reinstala siguiendo las instrucciones aqui https://chocolatey.org/install y se instalara correctamente.